# Change the position of the image being shown on mouse hover using jquery

Tags: jquery, mousemove, jquery-hover

The code below displays a larger image when the user hovers over a thumb version of the image and the larger image moves with the mouse. The code below works, but it positions the image to the right of the mouse. I would like the image to appear top center above the mouse.

I have changed the xOffset and yOffset values and that will change the up and down position, and move the image to the right, but not left.

Question is how can I modify the code to have the image that appears on hover to be top center above the smaller image?

I am using the latest jquery (1.9.1) via Google: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

the jquery:

```
this.imagePreview = function(){
xOffset = 0;
yOffset = 20;

$("a.preview").hover(function(e){
    this.t = this.title;
    var url = $(this).attr('alt')
    this.title = "";
    var c = (this.t != "") ? "<span class='preview-title'>" + this.t : "</span>";
    $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ url +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");
    $("#preview")
        .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
        .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        .fadeIn(1000);
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;
        $("#preview").remove();
    });
    $("a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    imagePreview();
});
```

the html/php:

```
    echo '<div style="display:inline;float:left;margin: 10px 4px;">
        <div style="background-color: #DDD;height:100px;border: 1px solid #111;">';
            if ($spacer_flag == 0)
            {
                echo '
                <a href="/view.php?im='.$image_dbid.'&w='.$row['id'].'" title="'.$row['word'].'">
                <img class="preview"
                src="'.$t_show_this_image.'"
                alt="'.$x_show_this_image.'"
                >
                </a>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '
                <a href="/reserve.php?w='.$row['id'].'" title="">
                <img
                src="'.$t_show_this_image.'"
                ></a>';
            }

            echo '
        </div>
    </div>';
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: @DeclanMcNulty - added the html

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it you want the image to be static and not move with mouse pointer. If this is the case, how about adding a hidden div containing the image you wish to show and styling it to be top centre above the smaller images in your css.

Then, on the mousehover event, do a simple

```
$("#previewDiv").show()
```

and then

```
$("#previewDiv").hide()
```

hide it again onMouseOut?